# SQL: Must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a Table that displays a teams salaries and I want to display their minimum, maximum and average salary for each team for each year.

My table looks like:

[image: Table description]

I run the following SQL:

```
SELECT MIN(salary), MAX(salary), AVG(salary), teamID, yearID FROM salaries;
```

But get the following error:

> ERROR: column "salaries.teamid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

What does it mean?

Comment: You'll need to add the non aggregate columns in a group by clause, i.e. add  `GROUP BY teamID, yearID` to the end of your query.

Comment: @StuartLC so I'm just curious -- why comment and not an answer?

Comment: @StuardLC:  I think a comment is appropriate, because I don't even regard this as a "question". Was there a question being asked? Looks more like a report of some observed behavior, and a comment is appropriate when we don't know what question is being asked, e.g. "What causes MySQL to return this error?"

Comment: I would argue this still should be an answer because until it is answered and an answer is accepted, it will show up in searches as unanswered.  Need closure.

Comment: You actually got this error in mysql? By default, mysql lets you get away with abominations like this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(salary), MAX(salary), AVG(salary), teamID, yearID 
FROM salaries
GROUP BY teamID, yearID;
```

Comment: answer should explain why it's the answer really - even if it is explained in the comments.

Comment: I don't know how to explain this.  The error message says it all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT MIN(salary), MAX(salary), AVG(salary), teamID, yearID FROM 
salaries group by teamID,yearID
```